# How do I take the price and turn it into a variable I can use

Tags: python, json

I am currently using and API and this is the output I am given.

```
['{"open":{"price":367.88', '"time":1593696600532}', '"close":{"price":364.11', '"time":1593720000277}', '"high":370.47', '"low":363.64}']
```

I have saved it as a string and split it at the commas. I just want to know how I can just take the price out of this list. The price changes every time the function is run.

Comment: Thats list of json strings, are you sure there would be only one element in the list (inside [ ] bracket)

Comment: And there's lot of prices, what specific one are you looking for here?  **367.88** or **364.11**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON to get the value. Please don't split your response with the ',' delimiter. Use string response instead.
Try using below code:

```
import json
response = '{"open":{"price":367.88, "time":1593696600532}, "close":{"price":364.11, "time":1593720000277}, "high":370.47, "low":363.64}'
resp_dict = json.loads(response)
print(resp_dict["open"]["price"])
```

Answer (score 0):

U should convert ur data to json by using `json.loads()`.

```
import json

data = ['{"open":{"price":367.88', '"time":1593696600532}', '"close":{"price":364.11', '"time":1593720000277}', '"high":370.47', '"low":363.64}']
data = ','.join(data)
data_json = json.loads(data)
open_price = data_json['open']['price']
close_price = data_json['close']['price']
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code will help you to find out.

```py
>>> import json
>>> data = ['{"open":{"price":367.88', "time":1593696600532}', '"close":{"price":364.11', '"time":1593720000277}', "high":370.47, "low":363.64}']
>>> data = ','.join(data)
>>> print(data)
{"open":{"price":367.88,"time":1593696600532},"close":{"price":364.11,"time":1593720000277},"high":370.47,"low":363.64}
>>> jsondata = json.loads(data)
>>> print(jsondata)
{'open': {'price': 367.88, 'time': 1593696600532}, 'close': {'price': 364.11, 'time': 1593720000277}, 'high': 370.47, 'low': 363.64}
>>> print(jsondata['open']['price'])
367.88
>>>
```